# Powershell Errors out correctly in ISE but doesnt in Command line execution

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I am running a command in powershell ISE that was exiting out how I expected, but when I moved the code to command line to execute in different environments, I wasnt receiving the error anymore. The error only happens in ISE. I have tried to use -sta on the command line like others posted, but have not had luck.

```
$SIEBEL_HOME\srvrmgr.exe /c "Run Command"
echo "Exit Code: $lastExitCode - Return Code: $?"
```

When I run that via ISE I get the following output:

```
Exit Code: 0 - Return Code: False
```

When I run that command on the command line I get the following output:

```
E:\powershell.exe -sta -file script.ps1

Exit Code: 0 - Return Code: True
```

As you can see, I am trying to check the return code and get the correct action in ISE, but do not get the correct result via command line.

I am wondering if there are different environment variables that Windows is using when running in ISE. I notice that when I run it through ISE the console shows the errors in red.

Comment: Your script should be executable.  What happens if you call it directly, rather than passing it as a parameter to powershell?

Comment: I get the same result calling it directly as an executable.

Answer (score 2):

The `$?` variable only checks the success state of the last PowerShell command executed, not external executables.

The `$LASTEXITCODE` variable detects the last exit code from external executables.

As you can see, these variables are used for different purposes, so you will not see consistency between them. For more information about them, run this command:

```
 Get-Help -Name about_Automatic_Variables
```

EDIT: Run this code to show how the $? variable works.

```
# Here we'll show a successful command, and then a failed .NET method call
Write-Output -Object "hi"; # Run a successful command
Write-Host -Object $?; # True = command succeeded
[System.IO.File]::NonExistentMethod();
Write-Host -Object $?; # False = command failed

# Here we'll show a successful command, followed by a failed executable call
Write-Output -Object "hi" | Out-Null; # Run a successful command
Write-Host -Object $?; # True = last command ran successfully
ipconfig /nonexistentparameter | Out-Null;
Write-Host -Object $?; # False = last command did not run successfully
```

For me, running PowerShell v3 Release Candidate, it works the same in the console as the ISE.

Comment: I agree that they should not be the same between LastExitCode and $?. The Success state of the last command is what I am looking for, and it gives the correct response through ISE. When I execute the same scirpt via commandline powershell and it gives the same error, I would expect the same result....but I am receiving inconsistent responses. I dont see why $? is treated differently between ISE and command line. I have been looking for an explanation why these are different so I can decide how I want to handle the error checking, but I cant seem to find one.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am also getting to correct outputs from your two examples. Its a odd scenario because the executable always returns exit code 0 even if there is an error which is why we couldnt write a bat script. Then when I was writing the power shell in ISE, I noticed that it was able to detect the error (somehow). Just wish I knew why the command line is not able to detect as its going to force me to code a custom error handling by parsing out logs.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution to your situation. If you want to write some code to determine the exit code of an external executable, you can use the `Start-Process` cmdlet to your advantage. In fact, I usually recommend that people use the `Start-Process` cmdlet instead of directly calling an external executable, because it helps handle argument values better. The other benefit, in your case, is that you can `-PassThru` and `-Wait` with `Start-Process`, which means you can get an object representing the process, which will also include its exit code.

```
$CliArgs = '/all';
$Process = Start-Process -FilePath ipconfig.exe -ArgumentList $CliArgs -NoNewWindow;
Write-Host -Object $Process.ExitCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell ISE handles errors differently than the PowerShell console.  In the ISE, all output from a console application to its stderr stream gets written to PowerShell's error stream.  I have yet to find anyway of changing this behavior.

Comment: Actually this answer is probably closest to addressing your issue.  What happens in command line if you redirect the error stream to the output stream: $SIEBEL_HOME\srvrmgr.exe /c "Run Command" 2>&1.  I suspect that $_ will return false, because PS encountered an error record in the pipeline.